# Need help identifying bricks from this list of images to buy them off Bricklink

Tags: part-identification

List of images is here: http://www.mediafire.com/?n9w4cxlatlvuh8g

Final build here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/25163007@N07/14560116177

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty large build. I would suggest that you go through and study the BrickLink Catalog, identify as many pieces as you can, and if you are stuck, come back and ask people to identify the ones you have trouble finding. I think people would be more inclined to help you this way, rather than having to do all the work for you.

Here is the entire layout of the BrickLink Catalog, which is a great place to start: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P

Another good way to begin a search, if you can't find something you are looking for, is to start with the Color Guide. Certain colors (like the Dark Blue in the aircraft you want to build) are fairly new, so there are not that many parts in that color, and it is easier to find them in the Color Guide rather than in the main catalog. Here is the link: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp?utm_content=subnav

Again, if you are stuck with something, feel free to ask, but you should be able to find most of the parts yourself.